# Google Chrome "couldn't load oauth2/oauth2_inject.js"

Tags: oauth, google-chrome-extension

I heave just read about google's OAuth2. As a start I tried to download the examples presented here:
https://github.com/borismus/oauth2-extensions/tree/master/samples

but when trying to load them to the chrome browser an error message showed up saying that

the extension can't be loaded because it **"could not load javascript oauth2/oauth2_inject.js' for content script".**

I've searched the web and didn't find this problem to be mentioned. What should I do in order to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Answer (score 1):

The samples do not contain the OAuth2 libraries. Download the "lib" folder from https://github.com/borismus/oauth2-extensions and place it inside the appropriate extension folder.